# Different behaviour of self referential model. Is it a bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, models, self-referencing-table

It seems that I found a bug. I have two similar models that behave differently.

I have a `Post` model that *belongs_to* an `Author`.

I have a `Task` model that is self-referencing.

Model code:

**app/models/author.rb**:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

**app/models/post.rb**:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

   scope :published, -> { where(status: 1) }

   after_create do
     puts '========================================='
     puts "author_id is present: '#{author_id}'"
     puts "what about task association? '#{author}'"
     puts '========================================='
   end
end
```

**app/models/task.rb**:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  has_many :tasks

  scope :published, -> { where(status: 1) }

  after_create do
    puts '========================================='
    puts "task_id is present: '#{task_id}'"
    puts "what about task association? '#{task}'"
    puts '========================================='
  end
end
```

Both `Post` and `Task` are similarly scoped, but behave differently:

```
Author.create.posts.published.create    # works

Task.create.tasks.published.create      # doesn't work

Task.create.tasks.create                # works
```

There is an `after_create` callback in Task model, where it should print the parent `Task` but it is nil despite `task_id` having the correct ID of parent.

Why is it behaving differently?

Comment: 'task' association is nil. But 'task_id' is correct.

Comment: Huh. Odd, seems to be a bug indeed. I get the following conditions on an associated model: `[["task_id", 3], ["status", 1], ["id", 3]]` and there's no way such model could exist with this logic. So, `task` association retains scopes: `Task#tasks` and `Task#published`. I wonder why. I'll dig into this, but you could as well get a gem `pry-rails`, place a `binding.pry` into your `after_create` and get to the source. I'll try as well.

Comment: @D-side pry is the yesterday :) already dig with it.

Comment: The problem behavior seems to be a scoping issue inside the `after_create` callback. The association works fine after you refresh the child object. Everything works as expected so long as you don't attempt to load the association inside of the callback.

Comment: Created [issue on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17382)